# Parsing an XML response on AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling

i have this response from a socket server:

> [DataEvent type="data" bubbles=false
>   cancelable=false eventPhase=2
>   data="Segunda vez"]

How can i parse this info?, for example if i want the *data* value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set an event listener on the object that is dispatching the event:

```
myDispatcher.addEventListener("data", dataEventHandler);
//would be better to have a constant.  perhaps DataEvent.DATA is the constant?
```

then call the data in the event handler:

```
function dataEventHandler(evt:DataEvent):void
     {
     trace(evt.data) //Segunda vez
     }
```